# Show or Hide field based on user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I have to show checkbox, only if `firstname` matches **abc** or `email` is **abc@gmail.com**.

```
var x = abc; //will come dynamically
var y = abc @gmail.com

jQuery("#firstname").on('change', (function(avalue) {
    return function(e) {

        if (e.targetvalue == avalue) {
            //show checkbox
        } else {
            //hide checkbox
        }
    };
})(x));

jQuery("#email").on('change', (function(avalue) {
    return function(e) {

        if (e.targetvalue == avalue) {
            //show checkbox
        } else {
            //hide checkbox
        }
    };
})(y));
```

This works good. But, if I enter username **abc** and email **abc@gmail.com**, then I again enter wrong email, the checkbox is hidden, which should not because name is already set **abc** correctly.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should combine those two checks into a single one like this:

```
var x = abc; //will come dynamically
var y = abc@gmail.com

function checkValues() {
    if(jQuery("#firstname").val() == x && jQuery("#email").val() == y) {
          //show checkbox
    } else{
         //hide checkbox
    }
}

jQuery("#firstname, #email").on('change', checkValues);
```

And while already using jQuery, you might also replace the last line by:

```
jQuery("#firstname, #email").change(checkValues);
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you check the field values separately. You need to check the email field value in the firstname onchange function, and check the firstname field value in the email onchange. Without that there is no logical relation between the two fields.